# How to get specific images from a website and display them in an Android App?

Tags: android, image, url, web, extract

Given the URL of a website I want to retrieve the logo and background image of the website and display it in an android app. For example from [this link](https://hackwestern.com/) I would want the background image and the hack western logo.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am trying to achieve this effect for a list of URL's of undetermined size until run time

Comment: I haven't really been able to come up with a way to retrieve the image from a website because I have been trying to get images for a list of url's with an undetermined size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `AsyncTask` for loading image from `URL`

```
 public class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private Bitmap mMyBitmap;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {
                URL url = new URL("https://hackwestern.com/images/logo_vert_spons.png");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                mMyBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(mMyBitmap);
    }

}
```

Then call it on `OnCreate` or somewhere you need:

```
new LoadImageTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply! I now understand how to go about retrieving the image, however would it be possible to do it for a list of events, without doing each one individually?